# Funcion Numbers Count

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a table in Word, with two columns and two rows, and I will fill each cell with a number from 1 to 9, is there any function that tells me how many numbers of each digit I have in the table?
Best regards!

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to get you started; it'll work with any table containing the insertion point:

```
Sub CountTableNumbers()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ArrNums(9), i As Long, vTxt As Variant
With Selection
  If .Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then Exit Sub
  For i = 0 To 9
    ArrNums(i) = 0
  Next
  With .Tables(1).Range
    For i = 1 To .Cells.Count
      vTxt = Split(.Cells(i).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
      On Error Resume Next
      ArrNums(vTxt) = ArrNums(vTxt) + 1
      On Error GoTo 0
    Next
  End With
  For i = 0 To 9
    ArrNums(i) = i & ":" & ArrNums(i)
  Next
End With
MsgBox Join(ArrNums, vbCr)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```